# multiple inheritance from classes

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

My main class inherits from two other classes . First my main Class :

```
class login: customMessage,BaseViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate  {
...
}
```

which `baseViewController` inherits from `UIViewController` .

Then I have `customMessage` class which inherits from `UIViewController` too .
Both of the classes need to inherits from `UIViewController` and When I inherit both of them at the same class , It gave me this error :

> multiple inheritance from classes customMessage and baseViewController

How should I fix it ?

Comment: I believe Swift is single-inheritance, like Objective-C.

Comment: @Avi , Yes,But what's the solution ?

Comment: You could have `customMessage` inherit from `BaseViewController`, and then have `login` inherit from `customMessage`.  Or not.  There's too much missing from your implementation and requirements to give an answer.  You could also refactor the common bits into a protocol with a default implementation and use it where it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift your class can inherit just from single class.
You can have a look on protocol and protocol oriented programming.
The other solution is:

```
// Class A inherits from UIViewController
class A: UIViewController
// Class B inherits from A and also from UIViewController
class B: A
```

In your example you said that your main class inherits from `BaseViewController` which inherits from `UIViewController` so if you want to create another class which inherits from `BaseViewController` and `UIViewController` you just need to do:

```
class A: BaseViewController
```

that's make it inherit from `UIViewController` too.